# How to draw logo or any graphics on the libvlc using wxwidget?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, libvlc

I am trying to draw image on libvlc window using wxwidget. Will capturing paint event on libvlc window solve the problem or there is better way?

Comment: maybe this helps https://github.com/tomay3000/wxVLC/blob/master/wxVLCMain.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the code but the code uses popup window I would like to have a logo painted on the surface of video after frame has been drawn